# How data structures cache aligned are invalidated in L1 cache line

Tags: c, performance, caching, cpu-cache

I am trying to understand the L1 cache mechanism of CPUs.

1. Let's suppose the CPU has 4 cores and the **L1 cache line size** is **64 bytes** with N entries for each core using **MESI protocol**.
2. Thus a memory reference is loaded aligned with the cache line size (the reference is some kind of data structure that holds 64 bytes exactly).
3. At this time, the **Core-0** modifies 4 bytes (at **offset 0**) in this cache line.
4. Then, **Core-1** references the same memory location. Thus, the Cache Coherence Protocol identifies this operation and copy the cache line in Core-0 to the Core-1 (avoiding reading from main memory).
5. **Core-1** thus modify 4 bytes (at **offset 15**) in this cache line.

**My question is this:** the Cache Coherence Protocol will invalidate the cache line in Core-0 or not? Although the modification are in different offsets.

Also, at this point, could someone tell what is the Cache Coherence Protocol (MESI) state for this cache line reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MESI protocol operates on cache lines so the offsets within a single cache line does not matter.

When core-1 initially requests for the cache line from core-0, it is copied over and the state for both cores is set to **S** (shared). When core-1 modifies the cache line, the cache line in core-1 is set to **M** (modified) while for core-0 it is set to **I** (invalid).